# Remove/hide a preference from the screen

Tags: android, preferences

I have an activity which extends PreferenceActivity.
I'm loading preferences from the xml file.
But in some cases i need completely hide one of the preferences from the screen based on my app state. There is a setEnabled method, but it's not exactly what i want. I want to remove that preference from the screen completely.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Yes, if you have a reference to both the `Preference`, and its parent (a `PreferenceCategory`, or `PreferenceScreen`)

```
myPreferenceScreen.removePreference(myPreference);
```

Comment: I might have answered my own question through this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4704360/956975

Comment: Unfortunately, it permanently removes the preference. Is it possible just to hide it?

Comment: It also doesn't work for me. The preference remains!

Comment: @Dmitry You can just gray it out with `setEnabled()`

Comment: @Dmitry You need to call `removePreference` on the direct parent, which you can get with `getParent()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336537/905686)).

Answer (score 219):

If your `Preference` is within a `PreferenceCategory`, you have to do this:

XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="category_foo"
    android:title="foo">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkPref" />
```

Java:

```
CheckBoxPreference mCheckBoxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkPref");
PreferenceCategory mCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_foo");
mCategory.removePreference(mCheckBoxPref);
```

Comment: To be fair, the above answer does say that you need the parent `PreferenceCategory`.

Answer (score 54):

In the case where the Preference is a direct child of the preference screen, here is some stand-alone code:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
Preference pref = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("mypreference");
screen.removePreference(pref);
```

Comment: This wont work if the preference is located inside category. you have to `findPreference` for the category, and remove the preference from the category

Comment: @MBH: Thanks for mentioning that caveat!

Answer (score 21):

If you are using [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat) you can set the visiblity in xml.

The preferences in your xml will be converted to AppCompat versions automatically. You can then use the '**app:isPreferenceVisible**' attribute in your xml

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="show.navigation"
        android:title="Show navigation"
        app:isPreferenceVisible="false" />

...
```

The attribute is documented at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/components-and-attributes

Adding `PreferenceFragmentCompat` is documented at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/#inflate_the_hierarchy

Example:

```
public class MySettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, new MySettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer!! OP asked to HIDE a preference, NOT remove.

Answer (score 9):

If you want something that will dynamically change the prefs for example on a SwitchPreference, I have found the best way is to put all my sub options into two category containers. Initially you'll have everything shown, then you just remove the bits you don't want. The clever bit, is you just trigger recreate when something changes and then you don't have to manually create anything or worry about putting things back in in the correct order.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  PreferenceCategory prefCatOne= (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("prefCatOne");
  PreferenceCategory prefCatTwo= (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("prefCatTwo");
  SwitchPreference mySwitchPref= (SwitchPreference)findPreference("mySwitchPref");
  PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
  if (mySwitchPref.isChecked()) {
    screen.removePreference(prefCatOne);
  } else {
    screen.removePreference(prefCatTwo);
  }
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    if (key.equals("mySwitchPref")) {
        this.recreate();
    }
}
```

The only downside that I can see with this, is there is a flash as the screen is recreated from scratch.

Comment: The case does not work, at least not in 22. But changing it to a Preference (even though it's a grouping of preferences) does work.

Comment: Rob, I just tested the above code in an API22 AVD and it's working just fine. Make sure your preference XML content matches your code. For the above example the SwitchPreference can be anywhere, but you need the PreferenceCategorys to be direct children of the PreferenceScreen.

Comment: I just got the Category as a Preference, no cast, and removed it. Worked.

Answer (score 8):

In your XML file:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:key="preferenceScreen">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="personalisation"
        android:title="your title here">

        <ThemedPreference
            android:key="animation" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

In your code:

```
PreferenceScreen pPreferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("preferenceScreen");

PreferenceCategory pCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("personalisation");
ThemedPreference pThemePref = (ThemedPreference) findPreference("animation");

pPreferenceScreen.removePreference(pCategory); //remove category
pCategory.removePreference(pThemePref);   // remove preference
```

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using v7 preference, it has `setVisible()` method. But I have not tried it yet. Accordingly you have to use `PreferenceFragment` instead of `PreferenceActivity`.

- https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#setVisible(boolean)

Comment: The accepted answer won't work for V7.
Using setVisible does work for V7

Comment: V7 also has `getParent()`, so you can actually remove the preference as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336537/905686).

Answer (score 3):

In the XML file you can make a hidden preference by leaving the title and summary tags empty.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="toddlerCam"
    android:key="save_photo_dir"
/>
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer to me. I've been looking for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since Android API 26 `getParent()` method is available: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getParent()

Though you can do the following:

```
preference.getParent().removePreference(preference);
```

Comment: This is also available for below API 26 with the androidx support library.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic way to do this that works regardless of whether the preference is under a `PreferenceCategory` or `PreferenceScreen`.

```
private void removePreference(Preference preference) {
    PreferenceGroup parent = getParent(getPreferenceScreen(), preference);
    if (parent == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find preference");

    parent.removePreference(preference);
}

private PreferenceGroup getParent(PreferenceGroup groupToSearchIn, Preference preference) {
    for (int i = 0; i < groupToSearchIn.getPreferenceCount(); ++i) {
        Preference child = groupToSearchIn.getPreference(i);

        if (child == preference)
            return groupToSearchIn;

        if (child instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
            PreferenceGroup childGroup = (PreferenceGroup)child;
            PreferenceGroup result = getParent(childGroup, preference);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple workaround:

```
//In your Activity code after finding the preference to hide:
    if(pref!=null) {
        pref.setEnabled(false);
        pref.setSelectable(false);
        //Following line will replace the layout of your preference by an empty one
        pref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_hidden);
    }
```

And create a preference_hidden layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Wherever is your Preference to hide (in a PreferenceGroup or at root) it will work!

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me perfectly. But for make sure I added: `android:visibility="gone"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate, and based on that mask, an alternative may be

```
SwitchPreference autenticacionUsuario = 
    (SwitchPreference) findPreference("key_autenticacion_usuario");

final EditTextPreference Username = 
    (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key_username_mqtt");
final EditTextPreference Password = 
    (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key_password_mqtt");

if (!autenticacionUsuario.isChecked()) {
    PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = 
        (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_mqtt");
    preferenceCategory.removePreference(Username);
    preferenceCategory.removePreference(Password);
}
```

All this must be within

```
public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is an English site. Can you answer in English?

Comment: Of course my intention was also to provide for people who do not speak English

Comment: @GustavoEduardoBelduma then you may need to read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/545026

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1.If you use support library, you can build a map of the tree of preferences and their parents, and then remove a preference by using its parent. Here's a function to generate such a map:

```
public static Map<Preference, PreferenceGroup> buildPreferenceParentTree(@NonNull final PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
    final Map<Preference, PreferenceGroup> result = new HashMap<>();
    final Stack<PreferenceGroup> curParents = new Stack<>();
    curParents.add(preferenceScreen);
    while (!curParents.isEmpty()) {
        final PreferenceGroup parent = curParents.pop();
        final int childCount = parent.getPreferenceCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            final Preference child = parent.getPreference(i);
            result.put(child, parent);
            if (child instanceof PreferenceGroup)
                curParents.push((PreferenceGroup) child);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

2. If you use the new android-x preference API, you can just set the visibility, by using [**setVisible**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.html#setVisible(boolean)) function on it.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference#setVisible(boolean)) and [Tea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448823/356895) `setVisible()` is available since version 24.1.0 of the Support library.

Comment: Have you looked at what I wrote? I specifically wrote that it's possible now... Also, the first solution helps with removal, which is a bit different than hiding..

Comment: Yes, I read your answer. I was referring to your 2nd point. It reads to as if the `setVisibile()` method is available from _android-x_ which I tried to clarify. No offense please.

Comment: Android-X is the one to replace all support libraries. There won't be any new versions of support library as we know them.

Comment: Correct. I am [aware of this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions). Still, people who are stucked with former versions can make use of the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing what I think you're trying to do (because I'm trying to do it now) it might be better to enable/disable the preference. Because removing it takes it out of the preference screen and you might not be able to add it back where you want it if you made the screen programmatically.

pref.setEnabled(false);
pref.setEnabled(true);

although this might be deprecated. It works for the use case that I'm going through right now.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is not to show the preference i.e. hide the preference then do the following

```
findPreference<Preference>("keyName").isVisible = false
```

*code is in kotlin*

> Note : This is AndroidX preferences (don't know if same with hold with earlier Preference)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in onCreate in the settings activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

You can initialize a global variable for the settings fragment and set it up like this:

```
settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settings_container, settingsFragment).commit();
```

Then you can do something like this further down in onCreate to set what should be hidden based on existing preferences, or to change what is hidden/visible based on conditions in your OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener:

```
settingsFragment.findPreference("setting key").setVisible(false);
```