# How to show and hide preferences on Android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

Is there a way to dynamically show and hide preferences?  In my case, I have a checkbox preference that would disable or enable one of 2 preference groups ("with-" and "without-handicap" groups).  While this would be the ideal GUI in a desktop environment, the "with-handicap" takes up nearly the whole screen, while the other, "without-handicap" takes up only a small portion of the screen.

Rather than showing both groups at the same time, I'd like to show only one of them at a time, and dynamically show or hide the 2 groups when the checkbox changes.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Se also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240326/remove-hide-a-preference-from-the-screen
for a better answer, in case you are using categories.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From a PreferenceActivity call

```
Preference somePreference = findPreference(SOME_PREFERENCE_KEY);
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
preferenceScreen.removePreference(somePreference);
```

you can later call:

```
preferenceScreen.addPreference(somePreference);
```

The only a little bit tricky part is getting the order correct when adding back in. Look at [PreferenceScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) documentation, particularly it's base class, [PreferenceGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html) for details.

**Note:** The above will only work for immediate children of a `PreferenceScreen`. If there is a `PreferenceCategory` in between, you need to remove the preference from its parent `PreferenceCategory`, not the `PreferenceScreen`. First to ensure the `PreferenceCategory` has an `android:key` attribute set in the XML file. Then:

```
Preference somePreference = findPreference(SOME_PREFERENCE_KEY);
PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference(SOME_PREFERENCE_CATEGORY_KEY);
preferenceCategory.removePreference(somePreference);
```

and:

```
preferenceCategory.addPreference(somePreference);
```

Comment: Grr, I guess there's no "visible" options in Android, after all.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: After removing some preference second call to 'findPreference()' returns 'null', how to add it again?

Comment: @Mickey Tin: just save the Preference (somePreference) above as a class member when you find it, then you can remove and add it as needed.

Comment: @dhaag23, It's working fine for main PreferenceScreen but not working for Inner PreferenceScreen, i.e. trying to add PreferenceCategory into inner PreferenceScreen.

Comment: If the preference is nested inside PreferenceCategory, search for PreferenceCategory instead of PreferenceScreen. Then try to referenceCategory.remove/addPreference

Comment: @sfszh This. Took me a while to figure that out; I have submitted an edit considering that.

Comment: I just noticed that this causes NPEs when the activity is stopped and restarted (e.g. because it is brought to the background and to the foreground again), as `findPreference()` will no longer find the preferences which were removed before.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly hiding/showing but if you only want disabling/enabling preference depending on another preference you can specify [`android:dependency="preferenceKey"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:dependency) or [`Preference.setDependency(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setDependency(java.lang.String))

Example from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#DefiningPrefs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="@string/pref_sync"
        android:summary="@string/pref_sync_summ"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <ListPreference
        android:dependency="pref_sync"
        android:key="pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:title="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
        android:entries="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_syncConnectionTypes_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [V7 preference](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html#setVisible(boolean)), it has `setVisible()` method. But I have not tried it yet.

Comment: It works, although you need to do some refactoring (new classes). Also, setting visibility to its present value again reveals some odd bugs (in 23.3.1), so be sure to check that visibility is not yet what you want it to be. Plus, switching from native preferences to preference-v7 results in an outdated LAF for the preferences, haven’t figured out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the hiding of the preference completely in the Preference, here is one example. Does not allow to make it visible again, though.

```
public class RemovablePreference extends Preference {

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    updateVisibility(); // possibly a better place available?
}

private void updateVisibility() {
    Context context = getContext(); // should be a PreferenceActivity
    if (context instanceof PreferenceActivity) {
        updateVisibility((PreferenceActivity)context);
    }
}

private void updateVisibility(PreferenceActivity activity) {
    updateVisibility(getPreferenceScreen(activity));
}

private PreferenceScreen getPreferenceScreen(PreferenceActivity activity) {

    if (activity.getPreferenceScreen() != null) {
        return activity.getPreferenceScreen(); // for old implementations
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        Fragment fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        if (fragment instanceof PreferenceFragment) {
            return ((PreferenceFragment) fragment).getPreferenceScreen();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void updateVisibility(PreferenceScreen screen) {
    if (!isVisible() && screen != null) {
        hidePreference(screen, this);
    }
}

private boolean hidePreference(PreferenceGroup prefGroup, Preference removedPreference) {
    boolean removed = false;

    if (prefGroup.removePreference(removedPreference)) {
        removed = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < prefGroup.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
        Preference preference = prefGroup.getPreference(i);
        if (preference instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
            PreferenceGroup prefGroup2 = (PreferenceGroup)preference;
            if (hidePreference(prefGroup2, this)) {
                // The whole group is now empty -> remove also the group
                if (prefGroup2.getPreferenceCount() == 0) {
                    removed = true;
                    prefGroup.removePreference(prefGroup2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return removed;
}

protected boolean isVisible() {
    return true; // override
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar: toggling a switch to hide or show two extra preferences. Check out the sample app from [Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) which bring some new preference types and fixes some issues from the official library. There's an example there to toggle a checkbox to show or hide a preference category.

In the fragment that extends PreferenceFragmentCompatDividers, you could use something like:

```
findPreference("pref_show_extra_stuff").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            findPreference("pref_extra_stuff_01").setVisible((Boolean) newValue);
            findPreference("pref_extra_stuff_02").setVisible((Boolean) newValue);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

*pref_extra_stuff_01* and *pref_extra_stuff_02* are the two preferences that are hidden when *pref_show_extra_stuff* is toggled.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding preferences dynamically, I created an if-condition upon whose value I decide whether I want the pref to show or not. To do the actual hiding, I have been using:

```
    findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key)).setLayoutResource(R.layout.hidden);
```

The tricky part is to make it visible again. There is no direct way to do it except to recreate the layout. If the value of the if-condition is false, which means the pref should be visible, then the code to hide the pref will never be executed, thus resulting in a visible pref. Here is how to recreate the layout (in my case, I am extending a PreferencesListFragment):

```
    getActivity().recreate();
```

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: `R.layout.hidden` appears to be a custom layout. Can you share it? PS: to reverse the operation, you would probably need to figure out the default layout used for preference items and re-assign that.

Comment: @user249408 here is the hidden.xml file


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in onCreate in the settings activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.settings_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

You can initialize a global variable for the settings fragment and set it up like this:

```
settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.settings_container, settingsFragment).commit();
```

Then further down you can set up an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener with a global SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to set up what should be shown or hidden when you change preferences:

```
// Global SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
sharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
{
    Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preferences, String key)
    {
        if (key.equals("switch key"))
        {
            boolean newPref = preferences.getBoolean("switch key", true);

            settingsFragment.findPreference("seekbar key").setVisible(newPref);
        }
    }
};

sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
```

Then in onCreate in the settings fragment you can do something like this to set what should be hidden based on existing preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("switch key", true)
{
    SeekBarPreference seekBarPreference = findPreference("seekbar key");
    seekBarPreference.setVisible(false);
}
```