# Hide a preference in a PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Is possible to hide a preference in a PreferenceScreen? I don't need to disable it, it must be invisible (sometimes)

Important: I need to keep the min API level 7+

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your logout button (Preference) is in the PreferenceScreen, do this:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen();
Preference logout = findPreference("logout");
if(screen != null && logout != null)
  screen.removePreference(logout);
```

Else if your logout button (Preference) is in a PreferenceCategory (which is inside a PreferenceScreen), do this:

```
PreferenceCategory category = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("category_name");
Preference logout = findPrefence("logout");
if(category != null && logout != null)
  category.removePreference(logout);
```

You can put whatever your preferences name is, this is for example for a logout preference, if you have another Preference (eg CheckBoxPreference) you need to cast that specific Preference before findPreference.

Answer (score 4):

Something like that should works:

```
Preference p = findPreference("your_preference_key");
getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

PreferenceScreen scr = getPreferenceScreen();

if(scr!=null)

```
     scr.removePreference(findPreference("preferenceKey"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Support Library v7 [Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference#setvisible), you can use the `setVisible` method. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this directly in xml with the AppCompat library.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54154665/114549