# android:visibility attribute in preferences xml not working? (Android 2.3)

Tags: android, xml, visibility, preferences

Take for example this small preference.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/sig_title" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListPreference android:entries="@array/text_display_entries" android:title="@string/sig_style" android:key="text_style" android:entryValues="@array/text_display_values" />
<CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/custom_font" android:key="tweaks_text" />
<CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/col_random" android:key="random_color_pref" />
<CheckBoxPreference android:visibility="invisible" android:enabled="false" android:title="@string/sig_show" android:key="show_sig" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The attribute android:visibility="invisible" for the last checkbox doesn't work; this attribute (or gone for that matter) doesn't work for preferences?

I don't have anything in the code to mess with its visibility, just curious why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

`android:visibility` is used to show and hide  `View`s but it's not valid for a `Preference`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) for `Preference` lists the available XML attributes, but none of them are what you want.

It *is*, however, possible to add and remove preferences from a `PreferenceScreen` programatically.

Answer (score 4):

For AndroidX users, add this directly to your preference XML

```
app:isPreferenceVisible="false"
```

Comment: Android 2.3 is not AndroidX

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `setVisible` method to change the visibility.

First, initialize the checkbox preference.

```
CheckBoxPreference showSigPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("show_sig");
```

then

```
// Show the check box preference
showSigPreference.setVisible(true);

// Hide the check box preference
showSigPreference.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: This did not work for me because `setVisible` isn't even an option for my `CheckBoxPreference`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference#setVisible(boolean)

Comment: I see, you are using androidx.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an older question that didn't previously have an acceptable answer to do this in xml.

Now with the addition of the AppCompat Library is IS possible do this directly in xml. See the complete example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54154665/114549