# PreferenceCategory.removePreference() returning false and thus not deleting preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I have seen all the questions related to this issue on SO but none of them worked for me. I am trying to remove a preference loaded from xml file in `PreferenceFragment` class but it is **not** removing that preference.

Here is my *pref_screen.xml* file

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory>

    <! ------------ />

    <Preferencecategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
         android:key="device_section">

        <Preference 
            android:key="sound"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_icon"
            android:title="@string/sound">
        </Preference>

        <Preference
            android:key="storage_settings"
            android:title="@string/storage_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_storage">
        <Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory>

    <! ------------------ />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is my *PreferenceFragment* class :

```
public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_screen);

        final Preference storage = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("storage_settings");

        if(storage != null){
            Log.d("SettingsActivity : ", "findPreference(storage_settings) not returning null.");
        }

        final PreferenceCategory device_prefCat = 
            (PreferenceCategory) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("device_section");

        if(device_prefCat != null){
            Log.d("SettingsActivity : " , "findPreference(device_section) not returning null.");
        }


        if(device_prefCat.removePreference(storage)){
            Log.d("SettingsActivity : ", "device_prefCat() returns true.");
        }else{
            Log.d("SettingsActivity : ", "device_prefCat() returns false");
        }
    }
```

I have checked log. `findPreference()` is not returning `null` but `removePreference()` is returning `false`. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `"I have checked log. findPreference() is returning null"` so no wonder that you cannot remove null `Preference`

Comment: @pskink Sorry, it is "findPreference() not returning null".

Comment: tried just to step-in with the debugger?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Could you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I found out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240326/remove-hide-a-preference-from-the-screen) the following should work for you:

```
Preference storage = findPreference("storage_settings");
PreferenceCategory device_prefCat = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("device_section");
device_prefCat.removePreference(storage)
```

Please note that I am **not** using `getPreferenceScreen()` here, intentionally.